# How can I ban a package from being added to Pipenv.lock and installed by Pipenv?

Tags: python, django, pip, pipenv

There are two packages which provide a module named `jsonfield`:

- [django-jsonfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonfield/)
- [jsonfield](https://pypi.org/project/jsonfield/)

Unfortunately, we have dependencies which depend on both and the two packages, while interchangable, store data to the database differently. This leads to [weird and hard to catch bugs](https://github.com/areski/django-admin-tools-stats/pull/49). Also, unfortunately, Pipenv doesn't have any deterministic order of operations when installing dependencies. Sometimes `django-jsonfield` is installed and sometimes `jsonfield` is installed. This means that sometimes, randomly, our application breaks because `jsonfield` is installed instead of `django-jsonfield`.

Is there a way that I can ban `django-jsonfield` from being added to `Pipenv.lock` so that only `jsonfield` will be installed?

Comment: The example given here (where you specify that a specific package only be installed on certain systems) might be helpful:  https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/advanced/#specifying-basically-anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are in quite a tricky situation... There is no clean solution that I know of currently other than manually editing your `Pipfile.lock` after each time it is generated.

You really should talk to the developers of the culprit projects:

- Either `jsonfield` and `django-jsonfield` should agree on different names for their top level packages.
- Or the projects that depend on `jsonfield` or `django-jsonfield` should agree on one of the two and ditch the other one.

You might be interested in this discussion and eventually weigh in:
https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/154. Of particular interest in your case is the fact that `pip` allows the overwriting of an already installed package when installing a new one.

---

*Untested*:

You could experiment with setting an unlikely marker on the unwanted dependency:

```
django-jsonfield = { markers="python_version < '2'" }
```

Comment: Using markers works. Unfortunate though, that it seems that "False" doesn't work.